# String as key in a mapping

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsmutablestring

I want to store an object in an `NSMutableDictionary` with a string key, so I have made the declaration like this:

```
[m_pMsgIdToStructMap setObject:pStruct 
                        forKey:[NSMutableString stringWithString:pStruct->szAsciiName]];
```

`szAsciiName` is declared as `NSMutableString *` in the .h file.
I am not getting any warning or error, but I want to confirm whether the declaration that I'm making is correct.

EDITED:

Hi,

```
main.m
-------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "string.h"

int main (int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    NSAutoreleasePool * pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];

    stringss* stringsss = [[stringss alloc]init];
    //NSMutableString* strs = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithFormat:"First"];
    [stringsss trail:@"First"]; //getting warning:Passing argument 1 of 'trail' from incompatible pointer type

    [pool drain];
    return 0;
}

stringss.h
----------

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef struct
{
    int a;
    int b;
    NSMutableString* szAsciiName;

}st;
@interface stringss : NSObject {

    NSMutableDictionary* m_map;

}
-(void)trail:(const char*)szAsciiName;

@end

stringss.m
---------

#import "string.h"

@implementation stringss

-(id)init
{
    if (self = [super init]) {
        m_map = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc]init];
        //pStruct->szAsciiName = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    }
    return self;
}
-(void)trail:(NSString*)szAsciiName
{
    st* pStruct = malloc(sizeof(st));
    st* pStruct1 = malloc(sizeof(st));

    pStruct->a = 10;
    pStruct->b = 20;
    pStruct->szAsciiName = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
    pStruct->szAsciiName = (NSMutableString*)szAsciiName;

    [m_map setObject:(void*)pStruct forKey:szAsciiName];

    pStruct1 = (st*)[[m_map objectForKey:szAsciiName]bytes];
}

@end
```

I'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception also.

Comment: Have you tried to read the object back to confirm it's correct?

Comment: What's the type of `m_pMsgIdToStructMap`?

Comment: @Josh:m_pMsgIdToStructMap is NSMutableDictionary.

Comment: So are you having trouble getting the object back out? Are you experiencing data corruption or something? I'm not sure what your question is. If it's just "Does this work?" then the answer is "Have you tried it?"

Comment: sorry will try it by reading the data.

Comment: @Josh & PengOne : I have tried with an example.please see the edit.

Comment: Jeff's right about the struct/object bit. The warning on the call to `trail` is because you're passing an `NSString`: `@"Blah"` but the method takes a `const char *`, aka a "C string": `"Blah"`.

Comment: @Josh:I have changed the parameter from const char* to NSString*.Now i'm getting EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception at the setObject:forKey

Comment: Using an NSMutableString as a key in an NSDictionary is a bad idea. Remember that the dictionary hashes its keys. It does that when you put them in. If you mutate the string, its hash will be different, but the dictionary has no way of knowing that, so if you then try to look up *the same string* (which the dictionary will ask for its hash, which will have changed, so the dictionary will look for the string by its new hash), it will not find it. Use immutable strings only. If you want to change the key, remove the object for the old key and add/change the object for the new.

Comment: Peter Hosey is wrong for once: using an NSMutableString as a dictionary key is safe, but it might not do what you want. NSDictionary keys are copied, so the actual key will be an immutable copy of your string as it was when it was added to the dictionary.

Comment: @Ahruman I always forget that NSDictionary copies its keys, but that doesn't change the point: Trying to look up the string that you mutated will fail, because the dictionary copied (and hashed) the old version. You can use a mutable string that you're not going to keep, since the dictionary will copy it, but if you are going to hold on to the mutable string (to mutate it later), you will not be able to find the same string in the dictionary after mutating it.

Comment: @peter Hosey:I can store a NSString as a key isnt it.I have modified my code.Please see the edit.

Comment: @Peter Hosey:The comments you have given here helped me in getting some idea about NSMutableStrings.Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

At a guess, pStruct is not an NSObject, its a raw structure (given your use of -> to dereference the szAsciiName).

That isn't going to work without more tweaking.  You can make a CFDictionary hold on to non-NSObject's by installing customer release/retain handlers.

Comment: Thanks.Using CFDictionary is new to me.I will try to do that.

Comment: @spandana: Pointers to non-objects are perfectly valid in CFDictionary, as long as you give it the right set of callbacks. You are using NSDictionary, which has no customization option (no callbacks), so you can only use Cocoa/CF objects with it.

Comment: @Peter Hosey:Yeah.To go with CFDictionary is a good idea.But i dont have prior knowledge doing that.I will try to do that.But is there any possiblity of adding a string as a key to the dictionary.

Comment: @spandana: I wasn't suggesting going with CFDictionary. I see no reason not to use NSDictionary. You should replace the struct with a model object class anyway, and doing so will enable you to use NSDictionary.

Comment: @Peter Hosey:yeah will do that with that NSData.